# what would be causing this error cannot find -lSDL_mixer

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to get SDL2.0.2 working in Code Blocks and I've followed the online tutorials but when I compile I get this error "cannot find -lSDL_mixer". I've got the linker setup as the tutorials instruct so I'm not sure whats going on. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post some screenshots(in link) about your build options.

Comment: Here's a screen shot of the full error https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlmmul87cds7tg5/Screenshot%202015-12-13%2000.29.01.png?dl=0 Here is a screen shot of the -L path https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9bq3z78rx551ok/Screenshot%202015-12-13%2000.41.36.png?dl=0

Comment: But there is no -L (capital L) for specifying the path to the library what I can see.

Comment: Apparently that worked, thanks. I wouldn't have expected that one to need a capital L.